# django 'User' object has no attribute 'get' error

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I am writing an simple django application and got stuck into this error, can some one please help me 
my views.py looks exactly as

```html
def custom_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboards')        
    return login(request, 'login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm)

def custom_logout(request):
    return logout(request, next_page='/')

def user(request):
        context = {'user': user, 'groups': request.user.groups.all(), 'dashboards': Dashboard}
    return render_to_response('registration/dashboards.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my forms.py is like

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
#from mhawk.models import Dashboard


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        username        = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
        password        = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
```

and the thing is I am trying to display the logged in username in an html page.

here is my trace back of error

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/

Django Version: 1.7.3
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mhawk')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  204.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
  31.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /user/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'
```

urls.py looks like

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from drinker import views, models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    url(r'^user/$', 'mhawk.views.User'),
)
```

dashboards.html:-

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ request.user.get_username }}. <br/>
    {% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}

<ul>
{% for group in groups %}
    <li>
        <strong>{{ group.name }}<strong> -
        
            {{ dashboards.d_name }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
        
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>



{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: please see my update I have mentioned error traceback, thank you

Comment: Please post the **complete** traceback message.

Comment: `User = request.User` - are you sure this shouldn't be `user = request.user`?

Comment: @soon I am not sure as I don’t have much knowledge in it

Comment: @jayj is that `HrttpResponseRedirect` ? It's should be `HttpResponseRedirect`

Comment: @Raja thanks i have done correction but still its giving the same error

Comment: @jayj Did you followed `@soon` suggestion ? After that what is the error you are getting

Comment: @Raja yes even now its the same error message as early

Comment: @jayj Your url is wrong == > mhawk.views.User it should be `mhawk.views.user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

**There is your problem, in urls, you are pointing not to a view, but to a `User`.** Python is case sensitive, you know. :)

---

Your problem is instead of `response`, middleware is getting a `User` object, so somwhere, instead of response you are returning a user, I don't see it in your code though.

Regardless, why don't you use django's authentication views? They do same stuff as you are trying to implement.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

def custom_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboards')        
    return login(request, 'login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm)

def custom_logout(request):
    return logout(request, next_page='/')
```

Oh yeah, and add this to your settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboards/'
```

And here is a promised `user` view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def user(request):
    # btw 'user' variable is already available in templates
    context = {'user': request.user}
    return render_to_response('dashboards.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: and should i take off user(request) in views.py

Comment: yeah you should, I'm typing up an edit, what you should do there too

Comment: So, from your code, here is the biggest suggestion I have for you. Only use first capital letter for classes, and not for methods or variables, it is a convention in practically all languages. Your problem was a just another proof of this. Otherwise, good luck in studying django.

Comment: my dashboards.html template is inside template/registration folder of my application where login and logout.html exists. but  i am getting template does not exist error

Comment: what about the dashboards template?

Comment: Then use `registration/dashboards.html` instead. You see, you need to give a path to a template, relative to the app's `templates` directory, unless you add paths to `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in settings

Comment: hiii alex may i know how to get the users group name using the username

Comment: If you are talking about `django.contrib.auth.models.Group`'s, then you should be able to get all groups user belongs to using this query: `groups = user.groups.all()`, that's of course if you got the user, otherwise: `groups = Group.objects.filter(user__username='username')`

Comment: yeah its the django models.Group's, i want to display group name as i have done it previously for username hope u remember, thank you

Comment: `User` has ManyToMany relationship with `Group`, hence the way you can get groups for a user is explained in my previous comment. I gotta go to sleep, I'll try to answer any questions you have tomorrow.

Comment: alex if you are there, please see my question that i have posted today and please let me know what can be done, thank you.

Comment: hello can some one please help me how to fetch the dashboards which are having Group as Foreign key with the same model above.its very urgent please help me