# ModelForm has no attribute get

Tags: python, django

I´m getting a ModelForm has no attribute 'get' error on my Django 1.8 Project. I´ve read similar questions on the topic but I haven´t found any solutions:

[django 'User' object has no attribute 'get' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336247/django-user-object-has-no-attribute-get-error)

[object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667845/object-has-no-attribute-get)

When Visiting the url: patients/add I´m getting the above error:

Here´s the code:

**forms.py**

```
class addPatient(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PatientUser
        fields = ['gender']
```

**views.py**

```
  def add_patient(request):
        if request.method == "GET":
            form = addPatient(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_user = Patient.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
                # login(new_user)
                # redirect, or however you want to get to the main view
                return HttpResponseRedirect('base.html')
        else:
            form = addPatient()

        return render(request, 'addpatient.html', {'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
class PatientUser(models.Model):
    children_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=1,
     choices=CHILDREN_QUANTITY_CHOICES, default=CERO)
    merried_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=175, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    citenzenship = models.CharField(max_length=175, blank=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^$', views.records_general, name="records_general"),
    url(r'^search/$', views.records_search, name="records_search"),
    url(r'^single/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.records_single, name="records_single"),
    url(r'^add/$', views.addPatient, name="addPatient"),

)
```

Can anyone help me identify the problem in my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've pointed your URL to `addPatient`, but that's the form. The view is `add_patient`.